# How to approach liquidambar with respect to pruning?

Tags: pruning, tree-care

I've got two young liquidambars, both planted in last two months, both 70-90 cm high, but from different nurseries. One of them is basically just one erect branch with leaves, and another has a main branch and 5-6 erect branches branching very low.

Is there any imediate need to prune the second one? Generally, should I leave these liquidambars alone (not prune at all during their lifetime), or they need some pruning?

Both nurseries referred them as just "liquidambars", no cultivar is indicated at all. They are fairly rare in my area, and I was happy to find and buy them, even though there was not much info on what the exact species they are actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tree is called *Liquidambar styriciflua*, American Sweetgum

[L. styriciflua](https://www.arborday.org/trees/treeguide/TreeDetail.cfm?ItemID=928)

These babies are 2 to 3 feet?  Leave them alone.  You said they were just transplanted?  Planted?  In pots or in the ground?

Allow them some time to acclimate to their  soil, environment.  Still need to know whether in pots or Balled/burlapped, bare root or if you planted them on your property?  Wonderful trees, big trees.  Did they have a third tree by any chance?  These trees will be powerful color and presence and would best be planted two closer together, a third on the other side of the property.... a huge Scalene Triangle.  Just an idea.

Leave them alone.  No hurry at all to be pruning.  Let them settle in.